# Use one select to determine which other selects on the form are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main category select on my form:

```
<select name ="main_category">
<option value = "maincat1">Main Cat 1</option>
<option value = "maincat2">Main Cat 2</option>
</select>
```

Dependent on the option value that is selected here I would like to make other selects visible/invisible.

I think hard coding an array will be the simplest solution for deciding which selects I want shown based on the option from the main_category select.

So:

```
maincat1_array = 'select1, select2, select3'
maincat2_array = 'select2, select4'
```

In this case if maincat1 is selected in the main dropdown I would expect to see:

```
<select1 display=""></select>
<select2 display=""></select>
<select3 display=""></select>
<select4 display="none"></select>
```

And if maincat2 is selected in the main dropdown I would expect to see:

```
<select1 display="none"></select>
<select2 display=""></select>
<select3 display="none"></select>
<select4 display=""></select>
```

I am aware that there will need to be some Javascript or JQuery involved, but am a total beginner. I know exactly what I want to do, but cannot work out the best way of doing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide/Show <select> depending on the other <select>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331010/hide-show-select-depending-on-the-other-select)

Comment: Start by learning how to change HTML element styles with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say do it like this:

First, give all the selects (except #main_category) a class so they can be referenced together.

```
var rules = {
    maincat1: ['select1','select2','select3'],
    maincat2: ['select2','select4']
}

$('#main_category').change(function(){
    var target = $(this).val();
    //hide all selects first
    $('.select-class').hide();
    //loop through the tags in your predefined rules, and show those elements
    $.each(rules[target], function(index, value) {
        $(value).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like it will be the one for me, however what am I doing wrong here... http://jsfiddle.net/d73aD/

Comment: jQuery wasn't included in your fiddle. It is working, the elements are just not displaying because they have no content. View the DOM in your developer console.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've now added to my actual code and no joy, I've updated the fiddle. What am i missing here? http://jsfiddle.net/d73aD/

Comment: <select1 class="select-class"></select> needs to be <select1 class="select-class"></select1>

Comment: The code in the latest fiddle doesn't seem to be trying to solve the same problem as your question.

Comment: First of all, your code needs to be wrapped in a document.ready function so you can bind your event handlers after the elements have been created. Secondly, since you are now referencing the element ID's, the values in your rules arrays need to be css ID selectors. http://jsfiddle.net/d73aD/3/

Comment: This was great, many thanks for your help, my earlier issues were to do with the fact that we weren't referencing the jQuery script correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion as a developer, you shoud use a request to a different page for load your options. I don't know if you are using a server-side scriptin, but I'd do like this:

---

### extra_page.scriptextension

```
<select name="secondSelect">
if option1 then
      <select1 display=""></select>
      <select2 display=""></select>
      <select3 display=""></select>
      <select4 display="none"></select>
else
      <select1 display="none"></select>
      <select2 display=""></select>
      <select3 display="none"></select>
      <select4 display=""></select>
end 
<select>
```

---

### end of extra_page.scriptextension

then in you main page you put something like that:

```
<select name ="main_category" id="mainCat">
     <option value = "maincat1">Main Cat 1</option>
     <option value = "maincat2">Main Cat 2</option>
</select>

<script>

$("mainCat").onchange(function(){
     $(this).load("extra_page.scriptextension")
});
</script>
```

In the extra page you can control a litte better how to populate second select, with options and categories you may have in you database.

It's just the draft of the idea... Of course you should use proper jQuery and javascript syntax, as well as the server side script you use.